# how to redirect php script after hang up in asterisk

Tags: php, asterisk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goqYK.jpg)

how to redirect php script after hangup?I need to redirect after hang up to php script.I have a problem about it.Because I'm newbie in asterisk dialplan.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. read this first to know about adding and formatting code snippets in your question
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

```
exten =>h,1,AG(agi-phpscript.php)
```

https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+h+extension

https://www.voip-info.org/wiki-Asterisk+AGI